# Python how to iterate over a list 200 elements at a time until I reach all elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

guys  I am currently writing to a time series but the limit for the list of points I can send is 200 elements at a time.

Currently the length of my list is 1586 elements. how do I process the first 200, then the next 200, until I reach the full length of 1586 elements ?

Lets say my dummy list has 1586 elements, what will be an appropriate  way of doing this?

```
dummy_list = [99,245, 69,00,27.. ,.., .., .., n]
```

Comment: Chunk the list, send chunks.